# Power Query Editor: Strip Leading Zeroes from Numeric Values Stored as Text

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, power-query

I am using Power Query Editor in Excel for Microsoft 365.

Table `A` has a column `ID` that holds a unique identifier. This identifier is usually numeric, but it sometimes contains text. Given this, I've set this column's data type as `Text`.

In some cases, values in this column appear numeric but have one or more leading zeroes (e.g., `"042"`). Since this is being treated as a text value, any leading zeroes are retained.

Table `B` also has a column `ID` of type `Text` which also holds a unique identifier that is usually numeric but sometimes contains text. The only difference between `A.ID` and `B.ID` is that when `B.ID` values are numeric, they never have leading zeroes.

I am trying to join (merge) table `A` and table `B` on column `ID`. Because of the situation described above, I lose many rows since, for example, `ID` values of "042" and "42" do not match since they are being treated as text.

I would like to add an applied step to my query that strips leading zeroes from `ID` values that are numeric.

I have tried changing the type of `ID` to `Whole Number` and back to `Text`. This strips the leading zeroes on numeric `ID` values but produces errors on non-numeric `ID` values.

Is there a way in Power Query Editor I can strip leading zeroes from numeric values that are stored as `Text`?

Or, is there a better way to approach this altogether?

Comment: your next step is to select on the column right-click and select context menu item Remove Errors OR Replace Errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***You can use this:***

- Create a Custom Column and try this Command,, removes leading Zeros from
  Numeric values stored as Text.

  `=Text.TrimStart([ColName], "0")`

Answer (score 0):

Can you go back to the source data and fix it with something like the following?

[image]